# How to work with files?

Tags: android

I'm working on android World Clock and i need to make internal file that will store all available GMT's,
how do i solve this or whats the better way to do this ???

```
private int hour;
private int min;
private int day;
private int month;
private int year;
private String amorpm;
private TimeZone gmt;
private int contries;
private String FILENAME;

public ClockRegions(){}

public String MygetTime()
{
    FILENAME = "COUNTRIES";
    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return ();//need to return after saving in the file array with all GMT's and the time in this location
}
```

}

Comment: You should use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) for this.

Comment: can you give me example how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use external files for this purpose, as they are not secure. Android recommends **Shared Preferences** for this purpose. Shared Preferences store data in the your app package in an xml file which is only accessible through your app. Data is stored in Key-Value pairs.

***To save data:***

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
      "com.example.your.package.name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String myTime = getSomeDate();
prefs.edit().putString("Your Key", myTime ).apply();
```

***To read data:***

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
              "com.example.your.package.name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String myRetrivedTime = prefs.getString("Your Key", "Default value if no data found");
```

To read more follow this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm)